# Set statement Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to open and existing excel file and copy a data from it into my active excel file. However, I keep getting

> "subscript out of range" error

in the `Set mySheet = Workbooks(myFile).Sheets("Sheet1")` line. the code below:

```
Sub OpenExcelFile()

'Declare variables
Dim myFile As String
Dim myData As Variant
Dim mySheet As Worksheet


'Get the path to the Excel file
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select an Excel file", MultiSelect:=False)


'Open the Excel file
Workbooks.Open myFile


'Get the worksheet that contains the data
Set mySheet = Workbooks(myFile).Sheets("Sheet1")


'Get the data from the Excel file
myData = mySheet.Range("A14:A83")



'Paste the data in specific cells in the current Excel file
ActiveSheet.Range("O15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


End Sub
```

I don't see what's the problem in this line

Comment: First of all, `Dim myWb As Workbook`, then change `Workbooks.Open myFile` to `Set myWb = Workbooks.Open(myFile)`, then `Set mySheet = myWb.Sheets("Sheet1")`. If you still get an error, then that workbook has no sheet named "Sheet1".

Comment: The `Open` method will return a `WorkBook` object so just save that to a `Workbook` variable and use that instead.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("O15:O84").Value = mySheet.Range("A14:A83").Value` to fix the other problem (pastespecial without copy)
`